# Vimeo badge and jscroll pane problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

I have this site that need to load videos from vimeo into a `<div>` element that will have a scroll attached to it.
But i have a problem. 
When the script that executes the jscroll pane come into play it messes things up allot.

[this is with jscroll](http://georgiunkovski.com/test-vimeo)

and

[this is without the jscroll](http://georgiunkovski.com/test-vimeo-no-scroll.html)

I`ve launched the site with static html wich you can view it here and get the idea of what i want to accomplish [www.georgiunkovski.com](http://georgiunkovski.com/).
I need to do this so the owner simply change the videos from the gallery and it would show on the site.

Cheers.

p.s. forgot to mention its in the collection section :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is you have to make sure that in jscroll u don't add so much sand.js as i see from your exaples, theres to many.

hope this helps ;)
<3